# fine-tune jQuery requirements for megamenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have created 4 level megamenu with using jquery. it works 80% according to my requirement sometimes it lagging between tabs. 
i'm not 100% satisfied with the jquery 
Can we refine the jquery further and is there any loopholes that I missed?
if anyone could point me in the right direction or what i did wrong, I'd really appreciate it(free to change any CSS/HTML).

note : once sublevel window open it displays default URL

for html/css/jquery https://jsfiddle.net/mg02rxra/4/

```
  <script>

    $(function(){
        var _timer;
        $('#menu > li > a').on("mouseenter",function(){
                 mainLoad(this); //, 1000);                  
        });
        $('#menu').on("mouseleave", function(){
                _timer = setTimeout(
                showDefault , 100);
                }).on("mouseenter", function(){
                clearTimeout(_timer); 
        });

        function mainLoad(param){
                    var li_ = param;
                    var x = $(param).parent();
                    var ul_ = x.find(".sublevel1");
                    $('#menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
                    $(param).addClass('active');           
                    $('.sublevel1').css('display','none');
                    $(ul_).css('display','block');    
        }                  

        function showDefault() {              
            $('.sublevel1').css('display','none');
            $('#menu > li > a').removeClass('active');
        }

        $('.sublevel1 > div > li > a').on("mouseenter",function(){
                var li_ = this;
                var x = $(this).parent().index() + 1;                
                $('.level1-a').removeClass('active');
                $('.level1:nth-child(' + x + ') .level1-a').addClass('active');
                $('.default, .info').css('display','none'); 
                $('.level1:nth-child(' + x +') .info').css('display','block');        
        });
        $(".xman").on("mouseleave", function(){
            _timer = setTimeout(
               showDefault2 , 100);
            }).on("mouseenter", function(){
               clearTimeout(_timer); 
       });

       function showDefault2() {              
             $('.level1-a').removeClass('active');
             $('.info').css('display','none')
             $('.default').css('display','block');   
       }  

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using jQuery for menu - sub menu functionality ? Jquery always lagging - because it always execute the code, once you done mouse over. But you can do this by using CSS by efficient way. Please use this link for getting this functionality : http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/opera-drop-down-menu

Also , i am attaching code as following

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

styles.css

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0fa1e0;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #0fa1e0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: submenu's of 'Products' show's on left side while image or Url related to Products must be show's on right hand side of same panel .. if user hover one of submenu(product 1, product 2) then it must show's the child menu's(sub product)

Comment: i think that all position can be set by css. You need to contact some css expert.